# Function execution is stopped in the middle

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, middleware

I write middleware to check user credential on each call.

As it is meant to work: I get ID token from the user. Checking for whom was token created. If the data are correct - I save them for future use .

```
middleware = function(req, res, next) {
  var storage = {};
  storage.ip = req.ip;
  storage.logged = false;
  storage.username = 'Guest';


  if(req.headers.authorization) {

    var base64Id = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');


    try {

      var decoded = jwt.verify(base64Id[1], app.get('salt'));
      console.log('decoded',decoded);

      Token.findOne({ jti: decoded.abc }, function(err, token) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }

        if(token.browser !== req.headers['user-agent'] || req.ip !== token.ip) {
          console.log('incydent: niezgodność ip lub przeglądarki');
        } else {
          User.findOne({_id: token.iss}, function(err, user) {
            if(err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
            if(user.name === decoded.name) {
              console.log('data are correct');
              storage.username = user.name;
              storage.logged = true;
            } else {
              console.log('data are wrong');
            }
          });  

          console.log('next step');
        }

      });

    } catch(err) {
      if(err.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
        token.deactivate();
      } else {
        console.log('ERROR!',JSON.stringify(err,null,4))
      }
    }

  } 
  req.storage = storage;
  next();
};
```

On console, my last line is 'data are correct', and line with `console.log('next step');` never has been executed. No errors are throw on console either.

Comment: Properly indenting code always helps

Answer (score 0):

`Token.findOne` is an asynchronous function (you give it a callback).

So the steps are :

- Enter Middleware
- Call `Token.findOne`
- Call `next`(last line of your code)
- `Token.findOne`'s callback is called (but your app is already in the next middlewares)

You should :

- Move `next()`  where you log `console.log('next step');` (and delete this last line)
- Add a `next(err)` in the catch block to propagate error if anything goes wrong